# DNS local area vs DNS Virtualbox

Tags: dns, bind

I have been trying to set up a DNS server on my system using Linux and bind. 
(I'm working with CentOS and Linux on my Windows 7)
On my Linux everything seemed to work:I can access my server and ping/nslookup/etc to the requested webpage on my created Linux server.

But on windows I'm unable to ping to my webpage hosted on my Linux server:

> Pinq request could not find host mmore.be Please check the name and
>   try again.

When I ask for `ipconfig -all` I realised that on my local area connection I got 3 DNS servers but I only need to access the 192.168.0.198...

What are these 2a02:1800:100::44:1 and 2a02:1800:100::44:2 doing?

Are they causing that I'm unable to ping to my webpage hosted on my linux?

If yes: can I remove or shut down these 2 DNS servers?

[image: My DNS for local and Virtualbox connection]

Answer (score 0):

> What are these 2a02:1800:100::44:1 and 2a02:1800:100::44:2 doing?

They're IPv6 DNS servers.

> Are they causing that I'm unable to ping to my webpage hosted on my linux?

Maybe. It's possible that your network prefers IPv6 over IPv4.

> If yes: can I remove or shut down these 2 DNS servers?

You can remove them, they're just DNS servers that look weird (IPv6 addresses, not everyone is used to it)

Comment: They're the default DNS servers for customers of the Belgian ISP Telenet. I have the same DNS servers on my home connection.